# Undefined or NAN is result when pulling from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, electron

I am trying to pull data from the database and display it in my app. Every variable is pulling except for firstPingPrice.  I am getting either an undefined or NAN result.

```
const parsePing = (str) => {
const qoutePattern = /"(.*?)"/g;
const pingStr = str.match(qoutePattern)
const pings = [];
pingStr.forEach(i => {
    if (i != '"resu"' && i != null && !(String(i).includes('<'))) {
        i = i.split('"')[1].split('|')
        let ticker = i[0] + 'BTC'
        let ping = {
            symbol: i[0],
            market: 'BTC',
            ticker: ticker,
            ticker_slash: i[0] + '/' + 'BTC',
            exchange: 'binance',
            timestamp: i[7],
            ping_info: {
                pings: Number(i[1]).valueOf(),
                net_vol_btc: Number(i[2]).valueOf(),
                net_vol_per: i[3],
                net_vol_per_num: Number(String(i[3]).split('%')[0]).valueOf(),
                recent_total_vol_btc: Number(i[4]).valueOf(),
                recent_volume_percentage: i[5],
                recent_volume_percentage_num: Number(String(i[6]).split('%')[0]).valueOf(),
                recent_net_volume: Number(i[6]),
                first_ping_price: Number(i[8])
            },
        }
        pings.push(ping)
    }
})
return pings
```

}
I believe this is the string. I added the firstPingPrice and assigned it i8....  I don't know if that's correct though.  The data is going into the db correctly as a number and I am trying to display as a number in my app.

```
const parsePing = (str, exchange) => {
const qoutePattern = /"(.*?)"/g;
const pingStr = str.match(qoutePattern)
const pings = [];
pingStr.forEach((i) => {
    if (i != '"resu"' && i != null && !(String(i).includes('<'))) {
        i = i.split('"')[1].split('|')
        let ticker = i[0] + 'BTC'
        let ping = {
            symbol: i[0],
            market: 'BTC',
            ticker: ticker,
            exchange: exchange,
            date: new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US'),
            info: {
                pingNum: Number(i[1]),
                netVolBTC: Number(i[2]),
                netVolPer: i[3],
                netVolPerNum: Number(String(i[3]).split('%')[0]),
                recentTotalVolBTC: Number(i[4]),
                recentVolPer: i[5],
                recentVolPerNum:  Number(String(i[6]).split('%')[0]),
                recentNetVol: Number(i[6]),
                btcPrice: '',
                coinHigh: '',
                coinLow: '',
                dailyVol: '',
                dailyPriceChange: '',
                firstPingPrice: Number(i[8]),
            }
        }
        pings.push(ping)
    }
})
return pings
}
```

Comment: What is `i`, and what is `i[8]`?

Comment: good question, i7 is timestamp and firstPingPrice is listed under timestamp so i assigned it i8... Im not the original programmer and i'm actually not a programmer, so just trying to figure this out on my own... sorry.....

Comment: This would be pretty simple to solve if we knew what `str` was. The code is splitting the string on pipes `|` and slotting the parts into the result object. Either the string doesn’t have a 9th part (index 8) or it isn’t parseable as a number. Without knowing the input it’s impossible to say what the specific problem is. `const x = ”zero|one|two”.split(‘|’)` gets you `x[0] = “zero”`, etc. and x[3] is undefined.

Comment: I added what i think is the string variable.  I don't believe it has a 9th part but i don't know how to change that....

Comment: You added another block of nearly identical code but you still haven't provided the value of `str`?

Comment: sorry, i did a search for str. in my code and that was the only code that referenced str..   I'll look again.   are you talking about the database schema saying whether its a number or string?

Comment: Your `parsePing` function takes an argument called `str`. I want to know what _value_ is being passed in for that argument when this gets called. What's the input to this function? It's obviously a string, and it's expecting it to be delimited by pipes and such, but what's the specific value? Are these being read in from a log file?

Comment: This is going to be tedious to explain in a stackoverflow comment conversation (and this isn't the appropriate place for lengthy discussions). I've started a [live session on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/live/OjXzL) if you want to pop over there and we can chat. I'll check in on it periodically to see if you're there.